# Start Postgres DB if needed with pg_ctl

Tags: postgresql

I know that I can start a Postgres DB using `pg_ctl start -D $DBPATH`, but that'll throw if the DB is already started. How do I start the DB only if it's not already running? Relatedly, how do I check if the DB is already running from only the file system?

Answer (score 1):

For that, use

```sh
pg_ctl status -D $DBPATH
```

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html) for details.